# Retain bounty awarded even if question is deleted

Tags: feature-request, bounties, deleted-questions

OK, I know bounty issues are trivial in the big scheme of things, but having a bounty taken away by the OP after awarding it is really making me upset.  (Maybe I should cut down on the caffeine?)

I've been getting irritated enough by bounties expiring without being awarded despite the fact that I gave a complete answer (questions with low views and no upvotes and the OP disappears). Losing bounties after they are awarded takes this to a whole new level of frustration.

I was awarded a bounty for [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373996/page-break-inside-doesnt-work-in-table-cells-with-rowspan).  Then I lost the bounty when the question was deleted ("voluntarily removed by its author").  I have no idea why the OP deleted the question, although I suspect it was simply because he was asking if something was possible and got the answer "no".

It is bad enough that all the work I put into answering the question is lost to the rest of the world because the OP deleted it, but to lose the bounty as well feels like a ripoff.  I see absolutely no policy reason for taking back a bounty that was properly awarded.

**Please change the policy so that bounties that have been awarded are not taken back when the question is deleted**.

Comment: What you are describing is highly atypical. Normally, an answer that earns a bounty is also positively scored. And if that was the case, the OP couldn't have removed their question. I think it would be a lot easier for the community to just undelete the question (assuming it's an on topic and valuable one) than to change the policy.

Comment: I voted undelete. I see no reason for the question to be deleted.

Comment: As for why the current policy is what it is, I suspect it's because bounties have been abused to quickly transfer reputation to secondary accounts. When that happens, it wouldn't make sense for the abusers to keep the reputation from the bounty, and removing the reputation on deletion is the quicker way to clean up the mess in one swift motion.

Comment: @Mysticial, Thank you.  We'll see if the OP deletes it again.  He's already deleted it twice.

Comment: @Yannis, I don't understand that use case.  If I want to transfer reputation to a new account what is my incentive to delete the question? I can come up with (copy if necessary) a fake question to use to transfer the points without needing to delete it. In any case, I think maintaining rewards for good behavior is more important than removing rewards for bad behavior.  See, for example, "innocent until proven guilty."

Comment: @OldPro Not if we upvote your answer. :):):)

Comment: @OldPro Given the voting now, he won't be able to delete it.

Comment: @OldPro In case of an abusive bounty, the OP wouldn't have an incentive to delete the question, but the community would. The problem here wasn't the lost bounty, it was the deletion itself, the question shouldn't have been deleted in the first place. And that problem was (relatively) easy to fix, the question is now undeleted, and your answer has a positive score, thus the OP can't self delete it anymore.

Comment: i wish i could have vote user ... instead post i really want to dv that user