# Why did I lose my +500 bounty after a question got deleted?

Tags: discussion, bounties, deleted-questions

About two weeks ago, I answered a question and was rewarded with a +500 bounty. See, I don't really much reputation. I'm at 448 on Stack Overflow. So when that question was deleted for whatever reason, I was shocked! I had +4 upvotes, and it was marked best answer. Based on my understanding, the OP couldn't have deleted the question himself, so why did I lose my bounty? And why in the first place would anyone lose reputation for a bounty after the question got deleted? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Gone It was awarded successfully roughly two weeks ago.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, then this is a bit of a mystery

Comment: @Gone I just wanted to know how this happened and why?

Comment: Fair enough too - would be interested in knowing how this could happen too

Comment: Can you link to the question?  (It won't help those of us under 10k rep on the site, but *some* people will be able to see it and the post history might shed some light on the matter.)

Comment: Worth to mention that if enough time pass (2-3 months, can't remember ATM) reputation is preserved even after deletion. However, two weeks are not enough.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180140/retain-bounty-awarded-even-if-question-is-deleted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was a [crappy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404546/languages-framework-suited-for-interactive-door-window-builder-webapp) that was looking for recommendations. The bounty **should have** been manually removed and the question closed a long time ago. You really should never have been awarded it in the first place. Well, that's the sucky thing about having a huge backlog of flags in the queue on Stack Overflow.

Upon deletion of the posts, the reputation events got reversed, which includes the bounties.