# Why did I lose the +(amount) green icon over my achievement page when I get reputation?

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

I used to get this:

[image]

But lately, this hasn't been appearing for me. I know I have been gaining reputation, but It's not showing the green icon for it. I don't think I really clicked anything different, so why did it disappear?

Comment: @Doorknob Huh??

Comment: It was a joke. ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/180276

Comment: It has been always appearing to me if there were any positive rep changes... [status-norepro]

Comment: @ShadowWizard, this is barely anything to do with the marked duplicate post.

Comment: It got everything to do @Chantola, it disappeared because your reputation dropped and reputation drops cause the highlight to disappear/not show.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's because [You lost 500 points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243437/why-did-i-lose-my-500-bounty-after-a-question-got-deleted).

The achievements shows your total rep, i.e -500 + whatever you gained, since it is still under zero it will not be shown.

But you can still click the achievements icon in order to solve the problem(the -500 will not be counted anymore)